# keras model not showing all layers after wrapping

Tags: keras, model, lstm, layer

I have a cnn model (called cnn_model). I wrap the model by time distributed to work on sequences. The new model is called lstm_model. why can't I see the cnn layers inside lstm_model?

The code:

```
    cnn_model = getModel(input_shape=(imageH, imageW), CHANNELS)
    image_frames = Input(batch_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS, imageH, imageW, CHANNELS))
    encoded_images = TimeDistributed(cnn_model)(image_frames)
    x = LSTM(output_dim=256, return_sequences=True)(encoded_images)
    outputs = TimeDistributed(Dense(NUM_EVENTS, activation="sigmoid"))(x)
    lstm_model = Model([image_frames], outputs)
```

lstm_model.summary() show only 5 layers, without all the cnn_model layers in it.
On the other hand - number of parameters indicate that the layers are indeed inside the new model. (500k parameters in lstm layers, 2.5 million parameters from cnn model. total of 3 million parameters in lstm_model)

help anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found them.
They are inside model.layers[1].layer.layers
After changing the layers (for me- unfreezing them), had to recompile the model. 
Now it works